# Does css and js libraries of canvas app and salesforce UI collide in anyways?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

After getting so many UI issues while using canvas app i am wondering if the css and js libraries of both canvas and salesforce UI collide with each other and not recognized by the browsers? Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas apps are hosted in an iframe, and as such are in a separate context. This means that, without conscious effort on part of the developer, there will be no interaction between the site's scripts and salesforce scripts.